# gedit text windows are opening with only 2 lines visible - how to fix?

Tags: gedit

All of a sudden my gedit new text windows open as a thin 2 line window.

[image]

I didn't find a setting in preferences.

---

How can I change this so new windows open normally ( i think the size of the last window was the previous behavior) so that New Window is more [image: window]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a workaround of uninstalling and reinstalling gedit.

However this was probably unnecessary, as in the process I observed the following:

- opening the first gedit window and then resizing it sets future window size
- opening *subsequent* windows and then resizing *them* does not work, the system continues to 'remember' the first window.  This is not how it used to work and seems illogical and confusing.  **So this seems to have been the problem all along**
- to effectively resize windows you have to close them all then open one and then resize that one window and then the resize applies to future windows.

Basically this seems like a bug, certainly compared to previous behavior

Comment: Probably the window size is remembered only when Gedit is fully closed, i.e., the size of the last window you closed is the subsequent new default window size.